# vlookup with worksheet function vba without fixing the range

Tags: vba

I want to write a vba code to do vlookup with worksheet function where my range is changing every time.I have written the below code:

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("master sheet")
with ws
.range("V2:V91004").formula = "=vlookup(C2,sheet2!$A:$B,2,0)"
end with
```

I want to remove the Range ie `2:V91004` and let my code take the range itself because my lookupvalue (column C)row number varies from 75000 to 100000. Pls suggest..

Comment: Do you mean that 91004 needs to be the last row used in column C? If so there is plenty online about how to find the last cell in a column.

Comment: The last row is not fixed...it can be anything in between 75000 to 1000000. i want my code to check that last row in Column C and give me output in column V.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way and its working fine.
.range("V2:V91004").formula can be replaced by **.range("V2:V" & range("C" & rows.count).end(xlup).row).formula**..

Comment: But Can anyone suggest if I don't want to see the Vlookup formula in Column "V" what should I use?